# Error 500 al configurar .htaccess: "AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 4 internal redirects due to probable configuration error."

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Estoy intentando configurar una URL amigable, cuando lo realizo, me da el error 500 del servidor.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^recovery/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ recovery?token=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

En el log de Apache aparece el siguiente error:

> ```
> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 4 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
> ```

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe este error?

Comment: ¿No tienes nada en los logs de apache?

Comment: Si, perdona, se me olvido incluirlo: le error es el siguiente.
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 4 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: ¿Qué URL intentas? Lo que dice el error es que estás redirigiendo infinitamente, probablemente porque una regla apunta a otra y esta otra a la primera.

Comment: Únicamente el archivo recovery redirecciona a la página principal, si el token es incorrecto. Pero la página principal no redirecciona a ningún sitio.

Comment: Lo que entiendo de tu regla es que si la url empieza por **recovery** envías la petición a **recovery** con un token. A mi me parece una redirección cíclica infinita.

Comment: Vaya, cierto, la directriz se repite con el archivo, no me habia dado cuenta, que tonteria. muchas gracias.

Comment: Ahora lo único que me pasa es que al hacer la redirección, no se cargan los archivos javascript ni hojas de estilo. Con la URL normal si los carga.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev eso da para una respuesta! Bien visto

Comment: Bueno, lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La regla que tienes en *.htaccess* es que si la url empieza por **recovery** envía la petición a **recovery** con un token. Es decir a la misma dirección y esto es redirección cíclica. Soluciónalo cambiando el segundo recovery por algo otro.